# How to generate random invertible symmetric positive semidefinite matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, matrix-inverse

How can I generate a random, invertible, symmetric, positive semidefinite matrix using MATLAB?

I found this Python code:

```
matrixSize = 10
A = random.rand(matrixSize,matrixSize)
B = numpy.dot(A,A.transpose())
```

But I am not sure if this generates random positive semi-define matrix `B`.

Answer (score 3):

The MATLAB equivalent of your code is:

```
matrixSize = 10;
A = rand(matrixSize);
B = A * A.';
```

This does produce a symmetric, positive-semidefinite matrix. But this matrix is not necessarily invertible, it is possible (though very unlikely) that the matrix is singular. More likely is that it is almost singular, meaning that the inverse will get very large values. This inverse is imprecise, and `B*inv(B)` will be different from the identity matrix by an amount larger than your tolerance.

One simple way of ensuring that `B*inv(B)` is within tolerance of the identity matrix is to repeatedly generate a random matrix until you find one that is OK:

```
tol = 1e-12;
while true
   A = rand(matrixSize);
   B = A*A.';
   err = abs(B*inv(B) - eye(matrixSize));
   if all(err(:)<tol)
      break
   end
end
```

The loop above will run only once most of the time, only occasionally will it need to generate a second matrix.

Answer (score 3):

For any eps > 0 and any nxk (for any k) matrix B the matrix

```
P = eps*I + B*B'
```

is positive definite and invertible.
If k < n and eps is small then P will be nearly singular, in the sense that it will have eps as an eigenvalue. When generating these matrices to test something, it can be handy to be able to generate something nearly singular.

---

MATLAB code to obtain `P`:

```
n = 10;
k = 1;
B = rand(n,k);
B = B * B.';
P = B + eye(size(B)) * eps(max(B(:)));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't speak Matlab

Comment: That's OK. Do you mind if I edit your answer with some MATLAB code?

Comment: Not at all, feel free.